# Issue with installing Intel open webrtc toolkit server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, intel, openwebrtc

I am trying to set up the Intel OWT server with the helo of this intel official document.

https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-server/blob/master/doc/servermd/Server.md .

I also checked these documents  https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-client-javascript  and https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-server.

After running

`bin/start-all.sh` in release folder
I am getting the below error. I tried in my local machine also to start a project but in local nothing is getting installed. Always 'No document found' error came.

In AWS, all command and installations are getting done but just stuck when starting the server. Please help me with that. It will be very helpful if anyone guides me through the whole installation process. Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to run **bin/start-all.sh --deps**